# Unable to Create range indexes using final-database.xml using marklogic datahub 5.1

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf, marklogic-10

I added few element range indexes in data-hub/src/main/ml-config/database-fields/final-database.xml

```
<range-path-index xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database">
  <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
  <path-expression>text('Date Publication')</path-expression>
  <collation>http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint</collation>
  <range-value-positions>false</range-value-positions>
  <invalid-values>reject</invalid-values>
</range-path-index>
```

and ran the ./gradlew mlDeploy -PenvironmentName=local --info

It ran successfully but the element range indexes which were added to the xml were not created.

MarkLogic version 10.0.3
Data hub version 5.1

Is this xml configuration not supported?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

We can do the same by using data-hub/src/main/ml-config/databases/final-database.json

But we need to also add the already existing indexes to this file